# VPN, remote connection, which one?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

This is the scenario. I have an application running on Windows XP. But I need to add another computer remotely that be able to connect to this computer running windows xp. The remote computer will definitively have internet but will need to connect to the host and run the application. Is that possible? How? Any software or special configuration required for this? If we need a VPN here, what will be the steps involved to configure? Need a clue.

Thank you.

Comment: You really ought to consider not using an ancient desktop OS as a server.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it right, you're running XP essentially as a remote app server that another XP computer needs to remotely access to execute an application like.

The include Remote Desktop can achieve this and it natively tunnels everything over TCP 3389 (that can be adjusted using a combination of registry edits and service file edits).

I've had to do exactly what you're asking about and used a dyndns account to find the server  since it was hosted using the ISP's DHCP .

There's tons of ways to do this w/o RDP and the offerings have increased dramatically over the recent period such as GotoMyPC, the old standby VNC,  more choices than you can think of and plenty to test.

Comment: Well, I really like this answer, so I think I have a clue where to start. Thank you!!